# How to get an app in kotlin to send data back and forth to a Django project

Tags: django, kotlin, python-3.6

Backend: Django
Frontend: Kotlin Android App

All data will go through the backend application but I want to make a simple connection between the two. Does anyone recommend any pages/articles or advice on how to do this.

Plan:
Enter a number in the app -> Send this number to the django app ->

searches in the DB (if there: display the info. else:add the info to the db)

return all the info to the app

I have made a few django apps previously but always just used a web based front end and never an android application and I wanted to do something new

Answer (score 0):

1. learn django ajax calls or django rest framework(drf)
2. learn request post in kotlin and request to your django view and after you can get json data from django server

Comment: Thank you, just advice in which direction I should go was perfect